# Custom Error Pages in Rails 4 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, error-handling, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I google'd around and tried a lot of things, but i'm not getting it right.

I'm on **Rails 4** and fairly new to rails in general.

Can Somebody explain to me the, (like it seems), basic steps to set up Custom Error Pages on Heroku ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok for the time i think this is fine.

Actually the public/ 404, 422 and 500 Error Pages are showing up on heroku if i modify them.

**Just edit**

- public/404.html
- public/422.html
- public/500.html

and on heroku its showing up fine.